# Keras model fit_generator odd error

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following code:

```
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        target_size=(128, 128)
    )

    datagen.fit(X_train)

    model.fit_generator(
        datagen.flow(X_train, Y_train),
        samples_per_epoch=len(X_train),
        epochs=30,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))
```

Which throws this unusual error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cnn.py", line 258, in <module>
          models = run_cross_validation_create_models(num_folds)
      File "cnn.py", line 205, in run_cross_validation_create_models
          validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))
      TypeError: fit_generator() takes at least 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Can somebody explain what is going wrong here, I am loading in a set of 3700 images.

Comment: What is the C++ part of the question?

Comment: Nothing... I have removed the tag and added some relevant tags.

Comment: I am assuming you have `(X_valid, Y_valid)` defined in the code. If so, check if you can train using `ImageDataGenerator` and `train_on_batch()`. If you could, then at least there is no error in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might come from the new API (Keras 2.0 released yesterday), the `fit_generator()` now takes `steps_per_epoch` argument instead of `samples_per_epoch`.

The `steps_per_epoch` is typically `samples_per_epoch` / `batch_size`.

You can find this info [in the documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/#methods).

Does it help?

Comment: Nope. I updates keras but still getting this exception

Comment: You might be a little more specific on the code you are using qnd version of your software.

Comment: im using Keras 2.0.8 and here is code: https://gist.github.com/creotiv/c7fb0328de22ec021f405ebbdc202100

Comment: What about the error trace ? You use fit not fit_generator.. it cant be the same error.

Comment: i just commented it cause it was not working. but i already find issue, i forget to pass steps_per_epoch to it(bad eyesight). Problem that it gave different error, so i didnt see problem.

Comment: Okay :) well glad you fixed it... the software evolves, the error message evolves probably too. This thread is old